# How to insert auto update date field in dynamics CRM?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, email-templates

I've created an email template for case entity. I want to insert a date field in that template so that whenever user is going to use the template the date field must be updated. For example, I've inserted the date today and the user is going to use it on February 06, 2014. The field must be updated automatically and the updated date must be shown to the user.

How can I use this in to fulfill my requirements. or is there any work around?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

As dynamic fields like the one you need cannot be added in an email template in the CRM (i believe it is not possible to add javascript into an html template),

you can achieve this with the following workaround:

1. In your email template add a string that will be easily recognizable and unique in the code. for example *DATE.NOW*
2. Then register an onchange event on the description field on the email form.
   In the event replace the *DATE.NOW* string in the description field with current date generated, printed in desired format in javascript.